# How can I access data from a PHP web app in my iOS app?

Tags: php, ios, virtualbox

I am attempting to make an iPad application that is a front end for an open source web application written almost exclusively in PHP. How can I access the data from the PHP? The only way I could think of is editing the PHP to encode the arrays and info in JSON then get that in the application, however this would not be very portable as the web application would have be changed.

The web application is called [phpvirtualbox](https://code.google.com/p/phpvirtualbox/) and the source code is available [here.](https://code.google.com/p/phpvirtualbox/source/checkout)

Comment: If you don't want to adjust your web application to serve data in JSON or any other format, then I guess your only way is to parse that webpage and extract data from it manually.

Comment: You can also create an API where you encode the resulting array from your PHP and convert the data to JSON. This way, you don't have to change your existing PHP code and your iPad application will still be able to talk to your web application indirectly via this API.